# SharePoint 2013 & Wordpress

Tags: site-template

How can I use Wordpress as a template for my sites in my SharePoint 2013 enviroment?

I was told it is possible, but have not had any luck finding any useful resources on how-to.

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress and SharePoint are different products. Wordpress templates cannot be used in SharePoint, and SharePoint templates cannot be used in wordpress.